# miRNA dataset for prediction experiments

Tags: gene, public-databases

I am from the field of Computer Science and I want to perform some experiments related to miRNA and mRNA prediction.I have been searching for datasets in this area and found one called mirWalk available at: http://mirwalk.umm.uni-heidelberg.de/

when I enter, for example, the Entrez ID 10608 it appears to me the following table (I have only put the first record):

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have two questions:

a) Can I use this dataset to try to make predictions about the interaction of this gene with, for example, miRNA hsa-let-7c-5p? For what I see this interaction appears in the table, but it seems it has not been validated.

b) What are the meaning of the different fields, there is no information about it in the website of mirWalk?

Thanks for your help and consider that I am a newbie in this bioinformatics field.